# How to set read_audience_network_insights scope in Facebook App

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a FB App set to read my ads' performances with my APIs and now I want to get the data about my ads' earnings.
Found this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/optimization/report-api/guide-v2) where they first tell you to set your app's scope with *read_insights* and *read_audience_network_insights*.
I already have read_insights, but I really can't find read_audience_network_insights . In my app's Dashboard -> App reviews -> Permissions and Features it doesn't show up in the list, nor for "basic" nor "advanced access" via App Review.
I tried first with a Business App, then with "None" type, because they tell you "if you don't find a scope try creating an App with a different Type".
This guy in the [FB community](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/599474397651327/) suggests to change the app status, but I also can't figure out how.

Any help will be appraciated, thank you so much.

Comment: No I didn't, sorry!

Comment: I have tried to fetch data using read_insights permission this works well for debug mode for release this needs business verification which I don't have.